Prometheus import old data using promtool error
Follow up with similar issue faced by other:
promtool tsdb create-blocks-from openmetrics doesn't show any data in Prometheus
I am facing a similar issue. I have a scrape API endpoint which prometheus scrapes as intended example:
my_custom_metric{metric_name="group.1"} 10 1713416400000
my prometheus scrapes and display correctly until i attempt to import data. I followed @thoro's comment and ensured that the data is in unix timestamp.
# HELP my_custom_metric Example of custom metric data
# TYPE my_custom_metric gauge
my_custom_metric{metric_name="group.2"} 60 1713247260
my_custom_metric{metric_name="group.2"} 65 1713247620
my_custom_metric{metric_name="group.2"} 70 1713247980
my_custom_metric{metric_name="group.2"} 75 1713248340
my_custom_metric{metric_name="group.2"} 80 1713248700
my_custom_metric{metric_name="group.2"} 85 1713249060
my_custom_metric{metric_name="group.2"} 90 1713249420
my_custom_metric{metric_name="group.2"} 95 1713249780
# EOF

However, after importing the old data in my prometheus has issues scraping the api endpont while returning error :
msg="Out of bounds metric" series="my_custom_metric{metric_name=\"group.1\"}"
msg="Error on ingesting samples that are too old or are too far into the future"

It looks like your data is rejected because it is too old for Prometheus. Try adjusting out_of_order_time_window accordingly to your data.
